# Need to change my Default mysql password

Tags: mysql, change-password

I have installed MYSQL in my machine. My default there is no password. But i want to protect my database with a password. Can anyone please send me the steps to change the password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ya know, while we're happy to help with programming problems, we're NOT here to look up documentation you could have TRIVIALLY googled for yourself... it is literally 3 seconds work to google for "change mysql password"... so yes, go RTFM...

Answer (score 1):

on mysql prompt

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or on mysql prompt

```
use mysql
update user set password=PASSWORD('your_new_password') where User='root';
flush privileges;
```

or on the shell prompt-

```
mysqladmin -u root password “newpassword”
mysqladmin -u root -h host_name password “newpassword”
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

[see more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-password.html)